# How to make dynamic sign up form without using any database?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make a dynamic sign up form where a maximum of 10 users can log in into my form, When I click on signup it will create a new user and then that every new user can save their information on text browser. Also, I want to make a save button that can show the profile of all new users and when I click on any one profile it will give me detail information about that particular profile(user). My version is qt5.12.0

I have made a static signup form where a maximum of 3 users can log in.so how can I convert my static code into a dynamic that a maximum of 10 users can log in?

This is my mainwindow.cpp when we clicked on the signup button, It will read signup_data.txt file and validate the username and password that I have enter from UI and username password in the text file.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QFile inputFile("signup_data.txt");
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);

       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
          QString line = in.readLine();
          QString line2 = in.readLine();

          QString line3 = in.readLine();
          QString line4 = in.readLine();

          QString line5 = in.readLine();
          QString line6 = in.readLine();
          qDebug() << line << "from text file";
          qDebug() << line2 << "from text file";

          QString username = ui->lineEdit->text();
          QString password = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
          qDebug() << username << "from UI";
          qDebug() << password << "from UI";

          if((username == "Harnish" && password == "Harnish") || (username == line && password == line2))
          {
              qDebug() << "enter in login";
              secDialog = new SecDialog(this);
              secDialog->show();
              ui->statusBar->showMessage("Login Correct",5000);
          }
          else if ((username == line3 && password == line4) || (username == line5 && password == line6)) {
              qDebug() << "enter in login3";
              secDialog = new SecDialog(this);
              secDialog->show();
              ui->statusBar->showMessage("Login Correct",5000);

          }
          else {
//              popupDialog = new PopupDialog(this);
//              popupDialog->show();
//              ui->statusBar->showMessage("Login Incorrect",5000);
          }
       }
       inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

I expect the output of this script is a dynamic signup form where multiple users can log in. I think here we have to put for loop in while loop but don't know how to make it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think that you should understand exactly how reading the file works.
You can imagine the [`QTextStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) as a bucket in which all the lines from the file have been added. Then, when you call [`readLine()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine) you simply remove one line from the bucket. Since removing items from an empty bucket does not make sense, you only do this while there are items in the bucket (and you check for this using [`atEnd()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#atEnd)).

My point is that just one `readLine()` call is enough to read the entire file. The example below will read the entire file.

```
QFile inputFile("signup_data.txt");
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream inStream(&inputFile);
    while (!inStream.atEnd())
    {
        QString readLine = inStream.readLine();
    }
}
```

The only change you must do in order to support unlimited logins, is to simply read the lines two by two, until reaching the end of the file.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString password = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    qDebug() << username << ":" << password << "from UI";

    QFile inputFile("signup_data.txt");
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
          QString readUsername = in.readLine();
          QString readPassword = in.readLine();
          qDebug() << readUsername << ":" << readPassword << "from text file";

          if (username == readUsername && password == readPassword)
          {
              logIn();
              break; // stop iterating, since the log-in was successful
          }
          else { ... }
       }
       inputFile.close();
    }
}
void logIn()
{
    qDebug() << "enter in login";
    secDialog = new SecDialog(this);
    secDialog->show();
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Login Correct",5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what yu want to know is how you read a dynamic number of user/password paird from a text file and compare them with user input.
The answer is arrays and loops, especially `std::vector` and `for`and `while` loops.

```
#include <vector>

//Create vector of QString
std::vector<QString> lines;
do
{
    //Increase vector size by 1
    lines.push_back("");
} while(in.readLineInto(lines.back(), 0)); // Try to read line from file and if it was successful repeat the above...
```

Now every line of your text file is in `lines`. Next you need to check every entry pair with the user's entry.

```
//By default everything is invalid
bool valid = false;
for(int i=1; i< lines.size(); i=i+2) // For each 2 entries in your file
{
    if ((username == lines(i-1) && password == lines(i)) // If username matches username in file and pw matches pw in file...
    {
        qDebug() << "login "<<((i+1)/2)<<" valid";
        // entry was valid
        valid = true;
        //Exit for loop early
        i = lines.size();

    }
}
if(valid == true) // If entry was valid...
{
    //Do your stuff
    qDebug() << "enter in login";
    secDialog = new SecDialog(this);
    secDialog->show();
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Login Correct",5000);
}
```

I assume your text file looks like this:

```
User1
Pass1
User2
Pass2
User3
Pass3
User4
Pass4
```

usw...

Comment: Hi, @Detonar  first vector code gives an error " call to non-static member function without an object argument ".

Comment: Yeah, of curse there has to be the object name instead. I fixed it.

Comment: There could also be a few more syntax or usage errors in there since i wrote this on the go and don't have the tools to test it right now but the algorithm should work just fine.

Comment: error: no viable conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<QString> >::value_type' (aka 'QString') to 'QString *'
I have commented on my while loop and in IF condition I have put your do and while statement but it give this error. I think this lines.back( ) statement needs one parameter.@Detonar It will be helpful if you create a chat room for this. thanks.